# Golang: How to Convert time.Time to a Protobuf Timestamp?

Tags: go, timestamp, protocol-buffers, unix-timestamp

I have a time.Time variable in Golang `10-30 00:49:07.1236` that needs to be converted to a Go [Protobuf timestamp.Timestamp](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/timestamp.go). Any idea on what functions can be used to accomplish this? Or am I looking at this from the wrong angle?

Comment: Recommend using `godoc` or going to pkg.go.dev to read the documentation for the libraries you are using. For example, go to https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#Timestamp

Answer (score 25):

See [`New`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#New) and [`Timestamp.AsTime`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#Timestamp.AsTime) in [`timestamppb`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb)

These support conversion to/from `time.Time` and `Timestamp`

Answer (score -4):

Below code will give convert time.Time to protobuf timestamppb format

```
import "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb"
timeNow := time.Now()
timestamp := timestamppb.Timestamp{
    Seconds: timeNow.Unix(),
    Nanos:   int32(timeNow.Nanosecond()),
}
fmt.Printf("as timestamp %+v\n", timestamp)
fmt.Printf("as time.Time %+v\n", timestamp.AsTime().Local())
```

Output looks like this:

```
as timestamp {state:{NoUnkeyedLiterals:{} DoNotCompare:[] DoNotCopy:[] atomicMessageInfo:<nil>} sizeCache:0 unknownFields:[] Seconds:1694773177 Nanos:777135000}
as time.Time 2023-09-15 15:49:37.777135 +0530 IST
```

Comment: Question: Convert given timestamp to time and vice versa. Not finding current time.

Comment: Use `timestampb.New(time.Now())`, as per the top answer.